# How can I optimize this range-based query?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, innodb

I have a MySQL database with four columns: `library_name`, a string, `function_name`, a string, `low_num`, a number, and `high_num`, a number. `low_num` and `high_num` together represent a range, and all the ranges belonging to the same library (having the same `library_name`) are mutually exclusive. I need to run support a query where, given a ~14,000 `str`-`num` pairs, for each pair it returns the row where `low_num <= num < high_num and library_name = str`. I've made my primary key `(library_name, low_num)`, and my current fastest query is `(select * from table where library_name = $name and $num between low_num and high_num limit 1) union (select ...) ...`. I.e., each pair gets its own query, and then they all get unioned together. However, it's still quite slow (takes around 20 seconds). I also run into memory issues when I do 1 query like this for the 14,000 pairs, so I'm having to break it up into ~14 queries to find 1,000 pairs each (but even one of these 1,000 pair queries on its own takes like 4 seconds). Any ideas how to speed up this query?

`SHOW CREATE TABLE`: https://db-fiddle.com/f/bjB1zLez2suhdCzt6itge5/0

`EXPLAIN SELECT` (for just one of the selects in the union): https://db-fiddle.com/f/hyq7aKN89soLZDPyxyJu5T/0

Comment: Can you please post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output in text, or in a dbfiddle, for your table? This helps us to see the precise column types, indexes, constraints you have already defined. Also the result of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for one of your queries (doesn't have to be the whole union of 1000 queries, one will do). This should be a standard requirement in any query-optimization question.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE`: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bjB1zLez2suhdCzt6itge5/0

Comment: `EXPLAIN SELECT`: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hyq7aKN89soLZDPyxyJu5T/0

Comment: `UNION ALL` is faster than `UNION` ... no deduplicating. May help. But not as much as @BillKarwin's temp table suggestion.

Comment: Can the low_num..high_num ranges overlap?  If not, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay here's the EXPLAIN:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| #3 | UNION | sym_large | NULL | range | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 1026 | NULL | 14000 | 11.11 | Using where |

The PRIMARY key of the table is on `(library_name, low_nm)` which are VARCHAR(255) and INT respectively. The `key_len` of 1026 indicates it is using both columns of the PRIMARY key: 4 bytes for the INT and 255*4 for the utf8mb4 string plus 2 bytes for the string length.

Probably filtering on both `low_num` and `high_num` is not possible, because both are inequality conditions. Usually, an index only helps to reduce the examined rows for N columns in equality conditions, followed by at most one column in an inequality condition. Your conditions are like one equality, followed by two inequality:

```
where library_name = $name and low_num <= $num and high_num >= $num
               (equality)          (inequality)         (inequality)
```

So only the first two terms of the search can be optimized by the index. The third search term must be applied "the hard way," by testing each row matched by the first two terms.

There's a possibility that applying the search to `high_num` instead of `low_num` would be better for reducing the number of examined rows, but that depends on the data. That is, if on average there are a smaller number of rows between `$num` and `high_num` than between `low_num` and `$num`, it could be more efficient.

If that's true, then using a different index on `(library_name, high_num)` instead may help. But it still would be limited to searching on two out of the three conditions. There's no way to filter on both inequalities in the same query.

You could also avoid the UNION if you load your 14,000 name/number pairs into a temporary table and do a JOIN instead of thousands of subqueries.

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_search_pairs (
  library_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  num INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  KEY (library_name, num)
);

...insert your search data into the temp table...

SELECT s.*
FROM sym_large AS s
JOIN tmp_search_pairs AS p
  ON s.library_name = p.library_name 
  AND s.low_num <= p.num 
  AND s.high_num >= p.num;
```

I think it's personal preference to use that inequality syntax vs. the `BETWEEN` syntax. They should optimize the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
    FROM ( SELECT * FROM sym_large
            WHERE library_name = ?
              AND low_num <= ?
            ORDER BY low_num DESC
            LIMIT 1
         ) AS x
    WHERE high_num >= ?;
```

The inner query is very fast because of the PK, and finds one row.  The outer part verifies that high_num has not been violated.  If you are sure there will always be a match, then simply do the inner query.

(I think this will run significantly faster than Bill's Answer.  Let us know.)

- EDIT * the original answer needed some corrections but once corrected is very fast. Inverted the relation operators and added DESC to the order by. The inner query will return the higher range in which low_num id lower the parameter thus the descending order, the outer query just verifies that parameter (?) is inside that range in case on non-contiguos ranges.